# CSS Image Opacity Fade Transitions with multiple elements (class)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Reference: http://www.sanandreasradio.com

I have a bunch of images as buttons, and they currently have an opacity change on:hover. This is faded using CSS transitions (I only have it set up for webkit browsers for testing purposes). When the page first loads, everything works as expected, you can hover over an image and it's opacity gradually increases, and when it looses focus vice versa.

When I click on an image I call a function (below) that sets the opacity of all of the image-buttons (class .station-button) opacity back to normal, then increases the opacity of the selected button to 1.0 (100%). Once that happens, the hover effect for other buttons no longer works (it also doesn't work for the selected button for some reason). The transition still works when clicking another button, but hover effects just stop working entirely.

The way it would be working (as of right now, since it doesn't take into consideration the current button which is at opacity 1.0), is that ANY button I am hovering over should have its opacity gradually changed to 0.6, EVEN the selected one (which I also need to fix in some way).

I have been staring at this for a long time without finding a solution.

How do I go about doing the totally fixed version, where un-selected buttons (opacity !=1.0) will fade to opacity 0.6 on:hover, and fade to opacity 1.0 on:click, and the currently selected will be unaffected by on:hover?

Here is the specific css and js.

CSS:

```
.station-button {
  opacity:0.3;
  cursor:pointer;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  -webkit-transition:opacity .3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease;
}
.station-button:hover {
  opacity:0.6;
}
```

JS:

```
function changestation(stationid) {
  mystation = document.getElementById(stationid);
  allofclass = document.getElementsByClassName("station-button");
  for (i = 0; i < allofclass.length; i++) allofclass[i].style.opacity = 0.3;
  mystation.style.opacity = 1.0;
  currentstation = stationid;
  loadnext();
}
```

Comment: Are you opposed to jQuery?  I know javascript elitists will hate me for asking this, but jQuery handles animations in less and simpler code.  It doesn't seem like you would have any sort of performance issue unless you had hundreds of these things on one page.

Comment: What is loadnext() do you have any errors?

Comment: ntgCleaner: For technical reasons, this project needs to be pure js. I know jQuery and other libraries have built in element selection, cross browser transitions with fallbacks etc, but like I said...
raam86: loadnext() deals with audio playing and loading, it's completely seperate from the UI. No errors for anything on the page, js and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forcing the opacity in the javascript (as a `style` attribute of the `img`) which is overriding the hover state.

Rather than forcing the opacity in the javascript, I'd use class names and just add or remove them as needed, letting the CSS sort out the opacities:

```
function changestation(stationid) {
    mystation = document.getElementById(stationid);
    allofclass = document.getElementsByClassName("station-button");
    for (i = 0; i < allofclass.length; i++) {
        allofclass[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    mystation.classList.add('active');
    currentstation = stationid;
    loadnext();
}
```

and

```
.station-button.active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.station-button:hover {
    opacity:0.6;
}
```

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adnrw/SJNMb/1/) with the code changes above.

Note that because you're hovering on the active one when you select it, it will only fade to 0.6 opacity, and then fade into 1.0 when you unhover it.

If this is a problem, you could add an extra class initially that forces the 1.0 opacity on selection, then set up a js listener to remove the class the first time it's unhovered.

Also, my version uses the HTML5 classList API so not great support: http://caniuse.com/classlist. It will be pretty easy to switch it over to `className` though for better browser support.

Comment: Yeah I figured that much as well. But just like you expected, I need the active one to always be forced to 1.0 opacity. I just find it strange there is no easy way to do this with simple js/css. Multiple classes and event listeners, so much for such a "simple" task.

Comment: If you just need the active one to always be 1.0, regardless of whether it's hovered or not (which isn't quite clear in the original post), you can just force it with CSS by adding `.station-button.active:hover` - here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adnrw/SJNMb/3/.